# How to integrate google earth API into desktop application?

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I am working on the project where I use coordinate lat and long and I'd like to pass a bunch of KMZ / KML files ( compressed coordinates of lat and long ) in paramaters to Google MAPS URL  that's why I ask if I could by anyway integrate google earth API or google maps API in my objective C desktop application ( by anyway as an API or a webservices)

Answer (score 0):

This control library I have written should help you out.

http://code.google.com/p/winforms-geplugin-control-library/